# Transpose Data using VBA Excel - Columns to Rows - Dynamic

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to transpose data in multiple columns from different sheets in a workbook into rows in another sheet (within the same workbook). I am attempting to make this code dynamic. For example, once the latest month closes, the code will pull the updated numbers-there are blank cells after June (so Cell D274 is blank).  Below is the code I have tried and a screenshot to visualize what I am attempting to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post the code as text instead of an image of text so people can copy/paste it if they want to.

Comment: You can do that with formulas - no need for VBA. Which version of Excel do you have? In column A on sheet Genesis: are these true dates? Same question for row 6 on Grossversusnet: are these true dates?

Comment: Please include your code as text instead.